# Dúvida com o print e com o for

Tags: python, python-3.x, for, print

```
for l in arquivo:
   Print(l)
```

Nesse arquivo estão as informações do nome, IP e Hostname.
Eu preciso printar o nome, IP e Hostname, porém nesse formato:

Nome *espaço de 10 caracteres* Ip *espaço de 10 caracteres* Hostname

Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Já pensou em separar os dados com ponto e vírgula, gerando assim um csv? A leitura fica bem mais fácil

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um código a partir do que eu entendi da sua pergunta e ele ficou assim:

```
# Faço a importação da biblioteca que manipula CSV.
import csv

# Abre o arquivo 'arquivocsv.csv' no mesmo diretório './' com o objetivo de ler 'r'.
arquivo = open(r'./arquivocsv.csv', 'r')

# Cria uma função e recebe o parâmetro para formatação, parâmetro esse que seria o arquivo lido
def formatar(arquivo):
    # Cria um laço de repetição para lada elemento dentro do arquivo lido.
    for l in csv.reader(arquivo, delimiter=','):
        # Utilizo um recurso onde posso substituir os {} por uma variável, seleciono posição por posição.
        # Printo cada linha com a formatação correta.
        print('{}          {}          {}'.format(l[0], l[1], l[2]))

# Executo a função
formatar(arquivo)
```

dentro do arquivo 'arquivocsv.csv' tenho o seguinte texto:

```
Joao,192.168.1.1,joao.exemple.com
```

Comment: certo, irei fazer isso nas próximas oportunidades. obrigado pela sugestão.

Comment: se quiser pode tabular o print formatado com `return(f'{l[0]}\t\t\t{l[1]}\t\t\t{l[2]}')`

Comment: sim, mas eu ainda prefiro utilizar a substituição na string, ao meu ver fica mais clean. mas é uma opção também.

Comment: Não deu certo, o erro que está dando é o seguinte: "IndexError: list index out of range", esqueci de mencionar que é um .csv

Comment: era uma informação importante, atualizei o código com a real situação. teste novamente, mas antes entre no seu arquivo CSV e veja se ele está sendo separado por uma vírgula pois pode que seu arquivo seja separado por outro elemento como ponto e vírgula ai será necessário modificar o parâmetro delimiter no laço. mas caso seja separado por vírgula basta executar o código trocando o caminho do arquivo.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara